# Shipping gear from Bangkok to Europe

Tags: europe, bangkok, shipping

Has anyone experience to share regarding affordable way of sending gear from Bangkok to Europe?

I'm thinking about shipping home my mountain equipment because it's not needed after I visit Bangkok. It's around 5-7kg of equipment and there is no rush to send it home so it can be shipped by sea.

Any advice on where to go for reliable service in Bangkok would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's home? Shipping to home somewhere else in Thailand is likely to differ a lot from shipping half way round the world...

Comment: Home is Europe. I'm also looking for where to go in Bangkok so that information is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, where do you want to ship it? US? because if your home is in China or Europe it's not really the same.

A friend used UPS Ground or a similar service to ship from Japan to France, a good amount of things (bigger than a backpack I would say). And it was around 100 dollars, but it takes a long time to come.

I think airlines don't have that high prices, I remember seeing a $60 fee to add a big bag to cross the Atlantic. So I don't know what's your next destination, but you can think of shipping it to the place you fly from, then you take it with you on the plane. I think you have some time to pick up your shipping once it arrived (it might not be free though)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Home is however Europe and UPS Ground doesn't seem to be supported from Thailand by UPS. At least I can't find it on their page :(

Comment: ok. I just found [something interesting](http://www.thailande.free.fr/poste.php). It's in French and outdated but gives a good overview, I suppose your package might cost you 5000 baht - apparently 130 euros. I have no idea what Thailand post is worth and you'd better search on other forums for feedback before doing it. You'll find information about the post office location at the end of the web page. Also [this](http://www.thailandpost.co.th/rate-result.php) might interest you. Text is rarely in english but numbers are the same.